# perror usage in this case

Tags: c, linux, error-handling

Can we check that my perror usage is correct? The background is these questions
[How to handle errors in execvp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535576/how-to-handle-errors-in-execvp)
[How to use perror with dup2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551485/how-to-use-perror-with-dup2)
and now I have this code which works but is the code correct?

```
/* Helper function that forks pipes */
int fork_pipes (int n, struct command *cmd) {
    int i;
    int in, fd [2];
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        pipe (fd);
        spawn_proc (in, fd [1], cmd + i);
        close (fd [1]);
        in = fd [0];
    }
    dup2 (in, 0);
    /*return execvp (cmd [i].argv [0], (char * const *)cmd [i].argv);*/
    if (execvp (cmd [i].argv [0], (char * const *)cmd [i].argv) < 0) {
        perror("execvp failed");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        return execvp (cmd [i].argv [0], (char * const *)cmd [i].argv);
    }
}
```

The full program is

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
struct command
{
    const char **argv;
};
/* Helper function that spawns processes */
int spawn_proc (int in, int out, struct command *cmd) {
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork ()) == 0) {
        if (in != 0) {
            /*if (dup2(in, 0) == -1) {
                perror("dup2 failed");
                exit(1);
            }*/
            dup2 (in, 0);
            close (in);
        }
        if (out != 1) {
            dup2 (out, 1);
            close (out);
        }
        if (execvp(cmd->argv [0], (char * const *)cmd->argv) < 0) {
            perror("execvp failed");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    return pid;
}
/* Helper function that forks pipes */
int fork_pipes (int n, struct command *cmd) {
    int i;
    int in, fd [2];
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        pipe (fd);
        spawn_proc (in, fd [1], cmd + i);
        close (fd [1]);
        in = fd [0];
    }
    dup2 (in, 0);
    /*return execvp (cmd [i].argv [0], (char * const *)cmd [i].argv);*/
    if (execvp (cmd [i].argv [0], (char * const *)cmd [i].argv) < 0) {
        perror("execvp failed");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        return execvp (cmd [i].argv [0], (char * const *)cmd [i].argv);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    int i;
    if (argc == 1) { /* There were no arguments */
        const char *printenv[] = { "printenv", 0};
        const char *sort[] = { "sort", 0 };
        const char *less[] = { "less", 0 };
        struct command cmd [] = { {printenv}, {sort}, {less} };
        return fork_pipes (3, cmd);
    }
    if (argc > 1) { /* I'd like an argument */

        if (strncmp(argv[1], "cd", 2) && strncmp(argv[1], "exit", 2)) {
            char *tmp;
            int len = 1;
            for( i=1; i<argc; i++)
            {
                len += strlen(argv[i]) + 2;
            }
            tmp = (char*) malloc(len);
            tmp[0] = '\0';
            int pos = 0;
            for( i=1; i<argc; i++)
            {
                pos += sprintf(tmp+pos, "%s%s", (i==1?"":"|"), argv[i]);
            }
            const char *printenv[] = { "printenv", 0};
            const char *grep[] = { "grep", "-E", tmp, NULL};
            const char *sort[] = { "sort", 0 };
            const char *less[] = { "less", 0 };
            struct command cmd [] = { {printenv}, {grep}, {sort}, {less} };
            return fork_pipes (4, cmd);
            free(tmp);
        } else if (! strncmp(argv[1], "cd", 2)) { /* change directory */
            printf("change directory to %s\n" , argv[2]);
            chdir(argv[2]);
        } else if (! strncmp(argv[1], "exit", 2)) { /* change directory */
            printf("exit\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `fork`, `exec`, `dup2` and `pipe`, like most syscalls in unix return < 0 (-1 usually) on failure and change `errno` global variable, which is used by `perror` to print message. So your usage is not wrong. By the way, `man` is an excellent resource that yields information about what a function does on failure.

Comment: There are a large number of errors in the code.  for instance,  the first time through the loop in fork_pipe() 'in' contains garbage.  the second parameter passed to execvp() needs to be a pointer to character strings, with a final NULL pointer.  That final NULL pointer is missing,  There are plenty more problems

Comment: @user3629249: The comment about `in` is correct — it should be initialized to 0.  The other comments are mostly incorrect; the second parameter to `execvp()` is a pointer to a null terminated array of `char *`, though the const-ness is a little askew (hence the cast), and the 0 in the initializers is a null pointer constant.  See also [How to fix these errors in my code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585978/how-to-fix-these-errors-in-my-code/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code:

```
 if (execvp (cmd [i].argv [0], (char * const *)cmd [i].argv) < 0) {
    perror("execvp failed");
    exit(1);
 } else {
    return execvp (cmd [i].argv [0], (char * const *)cmd [i].argv);
 }
```

has several problems.

1. execvp does not return, except if an error occurs, so if all works, the enclosing function will never return.
2. the value 'i' is already past the end of the array in 'cmd' due to the prior loop, so 'cmd[i].argv[0] is not correct.
3. cmd is not an array, of struct command, so should not be indexed
4. the first entry in cmd.argv is a pointer to an array  where the last entry is NULL.
   the execvp will work on that (and only that) array
   so all other pointers to arrays will be ignored

Comment: (1) The test is not necessary but the error reporting and exit is; the second `execvp()` is never executed.  (2) This analysis is wrong; the loop goes `for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)` rather than `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` — the latter would make your analysis correct. (3) `cmd` is an array in `fork_pipes()` so it is perfectly legitimate to index it.  (4) This analysis is simply bogus; the `struct command cmd[]` arrays are initialized correctly.