# Call to unavailable function 'system': not available on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am revisiting source code from a few years back and it used to compile perfectly but now there is one error in the project I can't figure out.

I have the following code:

```
void AssetsManager::destroyStoragePath()
{
    // Delete recorded version codes.
    deleteVersion();

    // Remove downloaded files
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WINRT) || (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM ==     CC_PLATFORM_WP8)
    FileUtils::getInstance()->removeDirectory(_storagePath.c_str());
#elif (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WIN32)
    string command = "rd /s /q ";
    // Path may include space.
    command += "\"" + _storagePath + "\"";
    system(command.c_str());
#else
    string command = "rm -r ";
    // Path may include space.
    command += "\"" + _storagePath + "\"";
    system(command.c_str());
#endif
}

NS_CC_EXT_END;`
```

I get the following error:

"Call to unavailable function 'system': not available on iOS"

How do I fix this error?

Comment: for removing assest you can use filemanger method `removeItem`. I am not quite sure with above code what you trying to achive.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way besides system. You may use NSTask (Process in swift)

Comment: Replacing the word "system" with NSProcess does not seem to work it says Use of undeclared identifier 'NSProcess'

Comment: Sorry it's NSTask in objective C

Comment: Nope same thing "Use of undeclared identifier 'NSTask'"

Comment: maybe that's not for iOS.  We use it in macOS. This is not your answer.

Comment: Ok I am looking for iOS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094451/call-unix-external-commands-with-arguments may help.